# Dynamic URL routing in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

A client of mine has asked me to setup some dynamic url routes in WordPress and I'm unsure on the best approach for achieving this.

The client is wanting a form submission to change the url from `http://website.com/contact-form` to `http://website.com/contact-form/success`

The issue is that the url will be dynamic and so I need to check for `http://website.com/*/success`

I have currently setup some ajax to handle the form submission and on success I am setting the hashbang however the client wants it to look like a real page.

Has anyone done something like this previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done easily from .htaccess .

**Example 1:**

For example, a rule for http://website.com/*/success will be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/success$ http://yoursite.com/contact-form/success? [B,L,R=301]
```

So all links that have a structure like: **http://yoursite.com/page/success** will be redirected to **http://yoursite.com/contact-form/success**

**Example 2:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/success$ http://yoursite.com/$1/success? [B,L,R=301]
```

So all links that have a structure like: **http://yoursite.com/whatever-page/success** will be redirected to **http://yoursite.com/whatever-page/success**

To find more regarding htaccess redirects and rules, search on google for:  htaccess redirect rules

Comment: Thanks for this, does the job however would it be possible for the routed page to also be dynamic? So if the user visits `yoursite.com/contact-form-2/success` they go to `yoursite.com/contact-form-2/` instead?

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your feedback. See example 2.

Comment: I tested it and it worked well. So I guess you have a problem with apache settings. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled. For more information, visit: http://askubuntu.com/a/508961